# Openfire Server send custom IQ to Client

Tags: plugins, xmpp, openfire

I want to send Custom IQ to client, but when I route packet to client that client get error `Socket closed by remote peer`.

Here is my code:

```
    List<JID> jidList = this.getUserRooms(session);

    IQ iq = new IQ(Type.result);

    iq.setFrom("com.innovate.ygoa");
    iq.setTo(session.getAddress());

    for (JID jid : jidList) {
        Element item = DocumentHelper.createDocument().addElement("item");
        item.setText(jid.toString());
        iq.setChildElement(item);
    }
    XMPPServer.getInstance().getIQRouter().route(iq);
    //  XMPPServer.getInstance().getSessionManager().getSession(session.getAddress()).process(iq)
```